# Problem showing characters in my site after modified files in a Windows IDE

Tags: php, file, netbeans, encoding, character

I have started working with an PHP file, which is running on Linux. I have connected the site for development using Netbeans from my windows vista computer.

It seems like when I save any file and upoload them to the server, and this files are php includes for the whole site, the site loose some configuration respect the Character Set, and starts showing wrong characters everywhere, even in the pages that I have not modified. However those pages are including the page that I have modified.

Do someone know why this can happen? and what is the best way to avoid this problem?

Comment: using utf is the best way to avoid this problem

Comment: This can have multiple reasons. What I can for sure is that it's encoding related. The easiest way to prevent that is to ensure that the encoding of the file you edit is not changed. How do you connect to your remote site? What is the default character set of the files on your remote side?

Comment: @k102: I think you mean `UTF-8`. Which is not a bad advice, but can be completely wrong if the files on the remote system are `LATIN-1`  encoded for example. So `US-ASCII` might be the best "free on guess" suggestion then, however that would be guessed and not specifically solve the OPs problem.

Comment: I've often found that I needed to save my files with ANSI encoding to get them to work properly on the linux-apache servers I've worked on.

Comment: @hakre `utf-8`, yes. i now that it can't solve ops current problem: i think that using this character set from the very beginning of the project will help to avoid such problems in future

Comment: Thank you guys... I will cheack all what you said

Answer (score 0):

And hoy do you guy know what is the actual Character Set of a project if you are starting to work with it, and is a old project? I am using netbeans from my windows vista.